# Loop through rows in table to update columns in a loop

Tags: sql, loops

So I figured I would re-write this whole thing as I worked through a bunch of issues. Here is my latest Code:

```
    DECLARE @LoopC INT = 1, @MaxOID INT, 
        @OID nVARCHAR(32), @Col nVARCHAR(6), @Colv nVARCHAR(3)
 SET @MaxOID = (select count(*) from #kentmp)
 SET @Col = 'col2'
 SET @Colv = '2'

WHILE(@LoopC <= @MaxOID)
BEGIN


   SET @OID = (Select OID
   FROM #kentmp where ID = @LoopC)

   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'update #kenintotmp set ' + @Col +' = ' + '''' + @OID + '''' 

   Print @OID
  --Print @Colv
   Print @Col
   Print @sql

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql

  SET @Colv = (select SUBSTRING(@Col, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Col), LEN(@col)))
  SET @Colv = @Colv + 2
  SET @Col = 'col' + @Colv
  SET @LoopC  = @LoopC + 1        
END
```

Currently my issue is that it is not updating the table with any records. My return looks like this:

```
0DE6A44203544775A164F81C264AF68B
col2
update #kenintotmp set col2 = '0DE6A44203544775A164F81C264AF68B'

(0 row(s) affected)
13FCE4FF16A44B149E116427AD47B5CE
col4
update #kenintotmp set col4 = '13FCE4FF16A44B149E116427AD47B5CE'

(0 row(s) affected)
1F81D9D6DAB04992A99CA0DC61894D7B
col6
update #kenintotmp set col6 = '1F81D9D6DAB04992A99CA0DC61894D7B'
```

Even when I try to just run a simple update on the table outside of this I get a 0 rows affected. This is from a temp table I made to work through the issue:

```
        CREATE TABLE #kenintotmp
(
    col1   varchar(255),
    col2    varchar(255),
    col3    varchar(255),
    col4    varchar(255),
    col5    varchar(255),
    col6    varchar(255),
    col7    varchar(255),
col8    varchar(255),
col9    varchar(255),
col10   varchar(255),
col11   varchar(255),
col12   varchar(255),
col13   varchar(255),
    col14   varchar(255),
    col15   varchar(255),
    col16   varchar(255),
    col17   varchar(255),
    col18   varchar(255),
    col19   varchar(255),
    col20   varchar(255),
    col21   varchar(255),
    col22   varchar(255),
)
```

Any Ideas why this is not working/updating?

Comment: show us what you did and what was your expected output

Comment: I am using a cursor for the OID loop (might change to while loop for speed if there is issues) but my thought was to have the column name as a variable but im not really sure how to do this. My thought was to start with a int and convert to varchar to use for the where column name is part for the update but as I stated I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think your cursor is missing some logic.  I don't see a FETCH statement which would load a variable on each recursive round.  I normally try and avoid cursors but in this case, it sounds warranted.  Anyways, here's a great article with an example of a cursor to help you clean that up.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/

Also, in order to utilize the the changing target column you will need to implement dynamic SQL in the body of the cursor.  Basically you will be using the cursor to construct an UPDATE statement that targets your table/column for that particular run through the cursor.  The UPDATE statement will be stored in a varchar variable.  You can either run each statement at the end of each cursor run, or simply continue to append the variable with the additional INSERT statements for each table/column that will be updated and then run the whole thing after the cursor completes.
From  a performance perspective, the second option will probably be better.

Just for a quick example of Dynamic SQL how you intend to use it;
you have a commented out update statement which I would assume you want to be the actual action that will be occurring.
Instead of just running the UPDATE directly, you will need to store that statement in a varchar variable like,

```
     DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'update #kenintotmp set ' + @Col +' = ' + @OID
```

On each subsequent run of the cursor, you would expect @Col to change and @OID to change.  Then at the end (either the end of each cursor run or after the cursor) run this;

```
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I ended up changing it to a while loop as that tends to be a bit better than the cursor. The dynamic sql was what I was missing...an over site for sure, thanks! My only remaining issue now is it will just not update the table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out the issue with the update. My table was completely blank. I added a single row with an insert (just gave a value of 1 for all columns) and then ran the update and it worked.

This one is all good. Thanks all for the assistance.